# how to take diffrence between cell array and simple integer array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

i have extracted 23 sentences from a text file which are divided and shown in separate line each sentence is given a number in ascending order {1,2,3,...}, code i used for this is as follows:

```
sentences = regexp(F,'\S.*?[\.\!\?]','match')
char(sentences)
```

now i did some processing and got filtered answer which shows a subset of sentences as shown below:

```
result = 1  4  5  9  11  14  16  17
```

the code i used for result is as follows:

```
result = unique([OccursTogether{:}]);
display(result)
```

now what i want to do is to show the sentences that are not present in the result variable for example the result i need is as follows:

```
result2 = 2 3 6 7 8 10 12 13 15 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

remember sentences is [1*N] cell where as result is simple array saving integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [setdiff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html):

```
%// Create an array containing the indices of all the sentences
AllSentences = 1:23;

%// Indices of sentences present
result = [1 4 5 9 11 14 16 17]

%// And not present
NotPresent = setdiff(AllSentences,result)

NotPresent =

  Columns 1 through 13

     2     3     6     7     8    10    12    13    15    18    19    20    21

  Columns 14 through 15

    22    23
```

I'm not sure to understand what is a cell array and what is not, but for cell arrays you can convert them to numeric arrays using `cell2mat` and apply the same methodology.

Eg:

```
AllSentences = {1:23};
NotPresent = setdiff(cell2mat(AllSentences),result)
```